# How to run a test case with different environment variables in xUnit?

Tags: c#, xunit.net

I'd like to run a test case multiple times with different custom environment variables.

An example:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(1)]
[InlineData(2)]
[MyEnvironmentData("foo", "bar", "baz")]
public void MyEnvironmentTest(int arg1)
{
  var foo=MyEnvironment.Get("foo");
  Assert.Contains(foo, new []{"bar", "baz"});
}
```

The test case should be run four times:

1. arg1=1, MyEnvironment.Get("Foo")="bar"
2. arg1=1, MyEnvironment.Get("Foo")="baz"
3. arg1=2, MyEnvironment.Get("Foo")="bar"
4. arg1=2, MyEnvironment.Get("Foo")="baz"

There can also be many MyEnvironmentData attributes. In that case, all permutations should be tested.

I have previously done this in xUnit.Net v1 by using a custom `TestClassCommand`, where I had implemented my permutation logic in the `EnumerateTestCommands` method and a custom `TestCommand` that would take care of setting the environment variables before each test run and cleaning up after. All other methods were delegated to xUnit's own TestClassCommands and TestCommands.

What would be the best way to implement similar setup in xUnit v2?